# Randomize an image for UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I call `[self randomizeBanner];` in `viewDidLoad;` on the main thread with `NSTimer` wherein I randomize the image of a UIImageView for a banner ad.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *bannerBackgroundImage;
```

...

```
- (void)randomizeBanner {

    NSInteger randomNum = arc4random_uniform(5);

    NSArray *arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@""],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@""],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@""],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@""],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@""],
                              nil];

   [_bannerBackgroundImage setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:randomNum]];

}
```

What is the best way to randomize the image of a UIImageView?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now, except for the missing image names?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you have no objections, then I guess nothing. I thought there might be a different/better way. What do you think?

Comment: I would create an array of image names and then just create one image from the randomly selected name rather then creating extra images that you're just going to throw away after they don't get picked.

Comment: A new image is picked every five to ten seconds so that array of images must have least five. Do you mean something else?

Comment: He means don't bother creating five `UIImage` instances, just to throw four away. Pick a random name, then create just one `UIImage` for that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*One way to achieve the same can be :*

Assuming your images are in the sequence `image1.png - image5.png`  then

```
UIImage * randomImage = [ UIImage imageNamed:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%u.png", 1+arc4random_uniform(4)]] ;
[_bannerBackgroundImage setImage:randomImage];
```

In your approach with each call to the function, the array is created again and again. With my approach there will be no need to manage an array of images you just need to manage the names of images in sequential order.

Comment: It is awesome answer!